# Xamarin Project works fine in Android, throws "405" errors in UWP when calling WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin, uwp, visual-studio-2017

I have an App that works fine when I set Android as the startup project but throws an error when I have UWP as the startup project. I have found, by commenting out code here and there, that the error is occurring when I make a call to my WCF. The second line below is causing the error:

```
        _client = new Service1Client(binding, Endpoint);
        var result = _client.CreateUser(Txt_UserName.Text , Txt_Password.Text);
```

The blah error message I can get so far is:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x0878DC3C (Windows.UI.Xaml.dll) in MyApp.UWP.exe: 
0xC000027B: An application-internal exception has occurred (parameters: 
0x172E2738, 0x00000006). occurred
```

Also apparently this was running right before it crashed:

```
#define BEGIN_DELEGATE_MAP(CLASS)\
    ref class delegate_proxy_type;\
    msclr::delegate_map::internal::delegate_proxy_factory<CLASS> m_delegate_map_proxy;\
    \
    ref class delegate_proxy_type\
    {\
            CLASS* m_p_native_target;\
    public:\
            delegate_proxy_type(CLASS* pNativeTarget) : m_p_native_target(pNativeTarget) {}\
            void detach() { m_p_native_target = NULL; }

#define EVENT_DELEGATE_ENTRY(MEMBER,ARG0,ARG1)\
    void MEMBER(ARG0 arg0,ARG1 arg1)\
    {\
            if(m_p_native_target == NULL)\
            throw gcnew System::ArgumentNullException("Delegate call failed: Native sink was not attached or has already detached from the managed proxy (m_p_native_target == NULL). Hint: see if native sink was destructed or not constructed properly");\
            \
            m_p_native_target->MEMBER(arg0,arg1);\
    }

#define END_DELEGATE_MAP()\
    };

#define MAKE_DELEGATE(DELEGATE,MEMBER)\
    gcnew DELEGATE(m_delegate_map_proxy.get_proxy(this),&delegate_proxy_type::MEMBER)
```

To further narrow down the cause of this error I created a simple standalone UWP app and I am trying to connect it to a WCF. On this program, I am getting this error message when I make the WCF method call:

```
 'The remote server returned an unexpected response: (405) Method Not Allowed.'
```

Any ideas on the cause of this error? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please provide more details like Configuration is debug or release, Platform is x86,x64 or arm, Visual Studio and Xamarin Version, Nuget packages used, etc.

Comment: I have narrowed down the error some more. Let me know if you still need all those details.

Comment: when asking a question about an error or exception in your code, it is EXTREMELY helpful if you tell us **specifically** what that error/exception is.

Comment: Sorry I deleted the part where I mentioned I can't get any usable error messages. I'll repost what blah error message I get.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of network environment your service is hosted. You need to enable different capability by different network environment (e.g, `Internet (Client & Server)`, `Private Networks (Client & Server)`, `Enterprise Authentication` etc). Please see this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh770532.aspx) for more details.

Comment: check with your network permission in windows solution properties

Comment: @Ronak where do I find windows solution properties? (using windows 10)

Comment: @Xavier I set those settings in the app manifest but I am still getting the errors. Thanks for the advice though, I'll keep reading your link.

Comment: @Xavier Actually this worked! Changing the settings in the app manifest! (It did not work on my test project but I'm sure there's another reason - but it worked on my main project!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @Xavier:

Changing the settings in the app manifest solved my problem! It was that simple. Thanks.